# Force decimal places to a string

Tags: vb.net

How can I add a trail of six `0` of decimal places to a number in string type?

I tried PadRight but didn't get the result that I wanted. For example:

```
125    ===to===>   125,000000
14,5   ===to===>    14,500000
```

so on..

Is there any function in VB.NET can do that or do I need to split the string then combine them?

Comment: `125.ToString("N6")`

Comment: Based on your example, it's not that you want 6 trailing zeroes but that you want 6 decimal places. An accurate description helps, including when you search the Web yourself for solutions.

Comment: This is really unclear. You must provide, which regional formats do you use. `12.1` means same as `12,1` based on the

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking, but if you want to add six 0's to a string then I would make a function, something like this:

```
private static string AddZeroes(string myString)
{
    //Makes an array that is 6 elements higher than the original string
    string[] myStringArray = new string[myString.Length + 6];
    //Sets the array to have all elements of myString inside of it
    for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i++)
    {
        myStringArray[i] = Convert.ToString(myString[i]);
    }
    //Adds the six 0's to the array
    for (int i = myString.Length; i < myString.Length + 6; i++)
    {
        myStringArray[i] = "0";
    }
    //Sets myString to an empty string, then adds all the contents of the myStringArray to it
    myString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < myStringArray.Length; i++)
    {
        myString += myStringArray[i];
    }
    //Returns the string that should now have six 0's added to the end
    return myString;
}
```

If you wanted a comma or decimal, it shouldn't be too hard to just add one right before the for loop that adds the 0's, and also make sure that the array is the length of the string + 7 instead, to fit that extra character.